# How to setup a static route between wireless routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have three wireless routers. Here is how the wan/lan interfaces look like:

Main Router, (connected to internet)
Wan: 24.x.x.x
Lan: 192.168.0.1

2nd Router: (masterbed)
Wan: 192.168.0.1
Lan: 192.168.1.1

3rd Router (Basement)
Wan: 192.168.0.1
Lan: 192.168.100.1

I am basically looking to set static routes between all three routers so that any device on any network can get to any other network in the house.

I have tried setting up static routes but something is not right.

All are connected to each other via ethernet.

Basic thing is; from the main router, i want to get to devices on both the networks (masterbed) and (basement)

What should my static route look like?
On the main network and the 2 satellite sites.

Thanks.

Comment: Static routes are possible (and would be almost trivial to set up), but... don't stack home routers like that. Use them as bridges.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so your problem is that you are creating a LAN-to-WAN configuration, which means you are creating 2 subnets isolated from each other in some terms. What you should try is a LAN-to-LAN connection so all users will belong to the same network and can talk to each other.

1. Connect to your main router and check DHCP is enabled and make it 192.168.0.1. Assign a static IP address to second router as 192.168.0.2 and third as 192.168.0.3.
2. Connect to the second router and use 192.168.0.2 and disable DHCP server
3. Connect to the third router and user 192.168.0.3 and disable DHCP server
4. Connect Main router LAN to LAN to second router and third router.

So up to here anything you connect to any router using the ethernet port will be part of the same network.

I am assuming you would like to also have a Wifi extension as well. If so follow the next:

5. Go to your second router and look for WDS settings or Wireless settings and select **Enable Bridge Mode** or **Repeater Mode**. Here you need to configure that Main router would be your DNS server (192.168.0.1).
6. Configure the WiFi name with the same SSID of your main router wifi using also the same password and security type (WPA2).
7. Once you are done repeat step 5 and 6 for the third router.

*This steps are all generic and they might vary depending of the brand of your routers *

Comment: No, that's not the correct way to do this; it has to be setup via a static route.

Comment: Not using static routing but I think this works fine in a home network.